# Trying to reduce run time of GAS code that copies sheets from multiple spreadsheets into a merged master version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

OK, so my main question here is if I can reduce the time it takes for this script below to run--it takes on average 8 minutes, 5-6 of which is just from copying sheets into another spreadsheet and pasting their original display values over them.

The purpose of this is to have vendor sheets from four different spreadsheets totaled in alphabetical order for sending as-is or for printing. I already researched trying do use PDFs instead, but have not been able to find a way to be able to print in a specific order with the resources I have--which do not include Adobe premium or access to printers for something like powershell scripts, which I do not know anyway. (Printing a folder of files does not actually print in sequential order, unfortunately, so generating PDFs of each sheet does not give me an option to print in alphabetical order.)

So, my workaround is to get an array of the four source spreadsheets, loop through those with another loop that goes through each sheet, and for each sheet make a copy to the merge spreadsheet, and then get and paste over each sheet with the display values as there would otherwise be issues with formulas not referencing. Then it calls other functions to rename the sheets without "Copy of " on them and then to place them in alphabetical order. For ongoing use, it starts by deleting all the old sheets except for an Index sheet from the merged spreadsheet.

Is there any way to reduce the number of calls? I looked into while loops, but it's different in that a lot of the "data" I'm moving is actual entire sheets, and I need their formatting as well. I considered just inserting the same number of sheets as I would be copying, and then repeating copying the same format which they all have, but that hits into an issue with the names--there can sometimes be duplicate named sheets between the source spreadsheets which have to be allowed in, and copying in just makes additional ones have a number at the end. That is fine, but I cannot set the names of the sheets before they are in the merged spreadsheet due to this, unless I can somehow check for duplicate sheet names and add "1", "2", etc, to them to allow them in.

Is the time running this just inevitable for this process, or can I speed it up?

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834873/copy-google-sheet-values-to-another-google-spreadsheet-and-create-new-sheet-with?rq=1
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758479/google-apps-script-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-spreadsheet-ids-and-copy-range

//Global variables. Runs from the merging spreadsheet, and the IDs of the four source Vendor spreadsheets
var mergeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var indexSheet = "Index";  //global for alphabetzing script
var monthly732 = '1TLH8HencpyH-4pDkQ1LetTErRxqYjh4gYC0XDdQxSVM'
var monthly827 = '19UfhUAvpFi0UJBF-rQoc4LWcL20-79nRltbSL-Wpj0A'
var quarterly732 = '1BRhoO_GcEoBmV_SoaV2xkw9BjgasAX3CorKxgWuEd2I'
var quarterly827 = '1JaAQtRIiCaQjO_A5S0p-VjHk8LUXExmqOYo75LxWf58'

//main function
function mergeTest2(){
 
deleteAllSheets();  //calls function at end of script to delete old sheets from merged spreadsheet

//Array of source spreadsheets for looping through
 var idList = [monthly732, monthly827, quarterly732, quarterly827];

 for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++){

//get sheets from each source spreadsheet
  var allsheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idList[i]).getSheets(); 

//For each spreadsheet, iterate through sheets except for Index and Template
// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Index") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Template") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Totals") 
      ) continue;

//For each sheet, copyTo merged spreadsheet, get original's display values and paste them on the copy 
//Using copyTo to get format of sheet, and allow for duplicate sheet names added

var mergeSheet = sheet.copyTo(mergeSpreadsheet);  

//Getting display values to override formulas to avoid REF errors
var sValues = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 
  mergeSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues);

  } //allsheets, end of for-loop for sheets within a spreadsheet


} //end for-loop of array of spreadsheets

//Get numbers of sheets from each spreadsheet for comparing to make sure all applicable ones were copied
//formulas set in Index page for comparing applicable sheets from sources (Vendors only) to make sure they equal merged Vendor sheets at the end
 var index_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(indexSheet);
    index_sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthly732).getNumSheets());
    index_sheet.getRange("D2").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthly827).getNumSheets());
    index_sheet.getRange("E2").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(quarterly732).getNumSheets());
    index_sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(quarterly827).getNumSheets());
    index_sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(mergeSpreadsheet.getNumSheets());

//Loggers used for testing, replace with getNumSheets above in final
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthly732).getNumSheets());
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthly827).getNumSheets());
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(quarterly732).getNumSheets());
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(quarterly827).getNumSheets());
    Logger.log(mergeSpreadsheet.getNumSheets());

slicerOfNames(); //call slicer function below for removing "Copy of " from sheet names.

sortSheetsByName(); //call function to put sheets in alphabetical order

} //end mergeTest2 main function


//Function to get sheet names except for Index, or that all have "Copy of " in name, and slice(8)
function slicerOfNames(){
  mergeSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("Copy of ") == -1) {
      Logger.log(sheetName);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(8));
      
    } //end if/else
  }) //end function(sheet)
} //end slicer function


//Function for alphabetical ordering of sheets within merged spreadsheet

function sortSheetsByName() {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == indexSheet) 
      ) continue;
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName());
  }
  if(aSheets.length)
  {
    ss.getSheetByName(indexSheet).activate()
    ss.moveActiveSheet(1)
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++)
    {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 2){
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 2);
       } //end if statement
    } //end for-loop
  } // end if(aSheets.length)
 }//end alphabetization function


//Function to delete old sheets from merged spreadsheet at the beginning of the script
function deleteAllSheets() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This will delete all sheets except the Index, are you sure?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
    case "Index":
    break;
    default:
    ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);}}
    
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sheets not deleted");
  }

} //end delete sheets function
```

Comment: From the question > OK, so my main question here is if I can reduce the time it takes for this script below to run Instead of using the Spreadsheet Service use the Sheets Advanced service. Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52586320/1595451
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/57226633/1595451
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/61110326/1595451 Resources - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletesheetrequest

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it looks you set values of disjoint ranges five separate times, which is very expensive. You could combine these into one line like `combined_range.setValues(2D_array)`. If you are worried about overwriting any existing data, use `combined_range.getValues()`, and then manipulate the returned 2D array using Apps Script prior to setting.

Following a similar philosophy, logging can be made much more efficient as well; in general, consider implementing a hash map to store and organize the results of  frequent spreadsheet calls. Alternatively, variables can also otherwise be used to condense, hasten, and improve overall readability.

Comment: If you're referring to this section that starts with:
`var index_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(indexSheet);
    index_sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthly732).getNumSheets());`
I had it in different set values because each one is pulling from a different spreadsheet. I probably could get those values to an array and then place once to improve a bit, but compared to the primary operations of copying and moving sheets around this part does not take much time and is really only for error checking.

Comment: @Micah, thank you for pointing that out. That was the most readily identified example on my end. I do see however many repeated calls in various loops and other potions of your code for getting (frequently the same) sheet and spreadsheet objects and their properties. As my answer outlines, it should be faster (and more reader friendly) to store and reuse the results of those getter calls using hash maps and/or local variables.